# Error: You can't change a Lightning Page's associated object

Tags: deployment, lightning-experience, flexipages

I am attempting to execute a deployment to a Sandbox using ant + force.com metadata tool v.37 and my deployment is failing with the error:

> *********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED ***********
>
> All Component Failures:
>   1.  flexipages/Practitioner.flexipage -- Error: You can't change a Lightning Page's associated object.
>
> *********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED ***********

My flexipage definition is not modified from a prior deployment which was successful and still uses the same sObjectType it always has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flexiPageRegions>
        ... snip ...
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <masterLabel>Practitioner</masterLabel>
    <pageTemplate>flexipage:recordHomeTemplateDesktop</pageTemplate>
    <sobjectType>HealthCloudGA__EhrPractitioner__c</sobjectType>
    <type>RecordPage</type>
</FlexiPage>
```

Does this error imply that the underlying metadata of the object that the FlexiPage refers to cannot be changed in any way? (Custom fields, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message was accurate. You cannot change the underlying `sobjectType`.

In the target org, at some point in the past this FlexiPage had been bound to the `Account` object and the deployment was attempting to change the sobjectType to `HealthCloudGA__EhrPractitioner__c`.

```
    <masterLabel>Practitioner</masterLabel>
    <pageTemplate>flexipage:recordHomeTemplateDesktop</pageTemplate>
    <sobjectType>Account</sobjectType>
    <type>RecordPage</type>
</FlexiPage>
```

Deleting the offending FlexiPage in the target org and redeploying was successful.